# Stackblitz makes HTTP requests to JSONPlaceholder but not to SWAPI

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest, http-headers, stackblitz

For some unknown reason, Stackblitz cannot handle requests to certain APIs.
It has no problem getting data from `sonplaceholder.typicode.com`, but cannot get data from `https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/`. When trying to fetch from SWAPI, it results in a console error saying `HttpErrorResponse`/`ProgressEvent`

Here is the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/http-basics-gpravn?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts), with the code of concern copied below:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  readonly URL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';    // works fine
  // readonly URL = 'https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/';           // HTTPErrorResponse

  posts: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getPosts() {
    this.posts = this.http.get(this.URL)    
  }
}
```

What is special about `jsonplaceholder.typicode` that Stackblitz lets us fetch data from it, and how can I get SWAPI to work too? And further, how can I mimic that on my own server?

Comment: Oddly, it's working for me in a different Chrome profile too. Why would it work in one and not another?

Comment: maybe cors or x-frame policies?

Comment: Those wouldn't be browser specific though, right?

Comment: They are browser specific. CORS and X-FRAME options are security features of browsers...

Comment: How do I check why one browser profile (of Chrome) has it and one doesn't ?

Answer (score 0):

I just checked your code and currently it is working fine. The issue might have been due to a temporary downtime of a service itself or other networking issues, hence it is always a good idea to explore details of an error and see what is a nature of a problem.